# cytoscape js traverse nodes by selector

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

How can I traverse the nodes in a `cytoscape js` network based on their selector?

I understand I can use the

```
cy.filter(".myselector")
```

which returns a complex object like:

```
0: ua {0: ua, length: 1, _private: Object, instanceString: function, spawn: function, spawnSelf: function, …}

1: ua {0: ua, length: 1, _private: Object, instanceString: function, spawn: function, spawnSelf: function, …}

2: ua {0: ua, length: 1, _private: Object, instanceString: function, spawn: function, spawnSelf: function, …}

_private: {cy: Wa, map: Map}

length: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method I developed to traverse the graph based on the selector (and obtain the element of interest, which in my case was the name of the node)

NB note how the name is retrieved, ie **_private.data.name**

```
var entire_object, no_of_objects, objects_array = []; 
entire_object = cy.filter(".myselector"); //returns a complex object with nodes matching ".myselector" filter
no_of_objects = entire_object.length; //the number of cytoscape nodes 

for (var i = 0; i < no_of_objects; i++){
  object_name = {};
  object_name = entire_object[i]._private.data.name; 
  objects_array.push(object_name);
}
```